# Canon Powershot TX1 LCD color issue

Tags: canon, powershot

Recently, my `Canon Powershot TX1`'s LCD flip panel shows a rounded moist like rounded borders at it its four edges, with rainbow like colors. What may be issue ? Does my LCD panel will `die` soon ? It is three years old now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does sound like LCD damage. The times that I have seen rainbow patterns like you describe, the only fix was a new screen.

I'm not sure how much that would cost, but you could [contact Canon and get a repair estimate](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/online_repair_tracking/consumer/digital_cameras/other_powershot/powershot_tx1?pageKeyCode=requestRepair).

Unless the cost was pretty low, I would lean towards using it as long as you can and saving
for a new model.