# What causes the rainbow colours on part of my LCD screen?

Tags: canon, camera, powershot, lcd

I have a Canon Powershot SX540. When I am taking pictures my LCD screen displays some rainbow colors. Can anyone help fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ralph and welcome to Photo.SE! Thank you for including an image of your problem :) Does this happen with all the photos you take? Are the rainbow colours always on the same location of the screen?

Comment: Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25621/9161

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canon Powershot TX1 LCD color issue](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25621/canon-powershot-tx1-lcd-color-issue)

Comment: yes it happens with all the photos. the colors appears everytime where there is too much light. i tried to reset it but nothing happens.

Comment: When there is *not* too much light, do the rainbow colors *not* appear?

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you mention that `the colors appears everytime where there is too much light`. The  [manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/3/0300022113/02/pssx540hs-cu2-en.pdf) on page 86 mentions an `Overexposure Warning (for Image Highlights)`.

You could try turning it off by pressing the down button when in playback mode.